# Cannot delete files with Filezilla

Tags: php, file, webserver, filezilla

Once I wrote a PHP script which should have downloaded a some images to a normal webserver.
Something went wrong with this script and now I have a lot of files in one directory with the filesize 0. When i try to delete one with filezilla the server just responses:

`550 nameOfTheFile.jpg: No file or directory`

what can I do the get rid of all this datatrash?

It seems like there are only the filenames saved on the server, but not the files

Comment: do you have shell access to the server?

Comment: no, i dont have shell access

Comment: Hm, strange message. Did you try right click -> Reload(Refresh) to check, if the files still exists?

Comment: yes and I also reconnected with the server as well

Comment: Hmmm in that case, perhaps write a php script to read through the directory and unset the files? Since PHP created them, it stands to reason that it should be able to remove them.

Comment: Maybe the permissions to the files are not correct. Write a short PHP script with rmdir() to delete the folder.

Comment: @MarcelBalzer that didnt work either

Comment: Did you turn on error_reporting to E_ALL? What error is thrown by rmdir()?

Comment: Something you can try. Create a small `.jpg` file (with actual image content) and upload it as the other filenames in the folder (to overwrite), and try to delete them after. Have you tried to create a file that will `chmod` them to a different permission setting? I think something like this happened to me before, and that is what I ended up doing, which worked.

Comment: I'm not sure if I still have that piece of code that I wrote, but if my memory serves me right, it had an upload feature with a `chmod` directive set to `0777` and I would simply choose a file from my computer of the same name from the one being on my server, which would overwrite it. If you can either upload via FTP or by using an upload script, is worth trying.

Comment: i was able to create a file with the exact same name such another file in the directory, so i had two files with the same name, after that i was able to delete one of them, but not both. after refreshing the directory there was one file left, with the filesize of 0, no matter wich file i have deleted

Comment: Are you able to enter raw ftp commands, such as: `dele filename.jpg` ?

Comment: Plus, if you have Cpanel, try and do it from the file manager in there. Cpanel has 2 different types of file managers, one of them may work. If that doesn't work, then try and contact the system admin.

Comment: You can also try Midnight Commander from the command line http://www.midnight-commander.org/ which can deal with unusual situations.

Comment: Have a look at a piece of code someone wrote, which removes everything in a directory and the directory itself. https://community.x10hosting.com/threads/550-cant-remove-directory-directory-not-empty.83973/ near the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a piece of code I found **[here](https://community.x10hosting.com/threads/550-cant-remove-directory-directory-not-empty.83973/)**

[As per original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636218/cannot-delete-files-with-filezilla/20640202#comment30890740_20636218)

```
<?php

$dir_stack = array('test/'); // put the directory to delete here **NOTE** everything in this will be deleted.
$i = 0;
while ($i <= count($dir_stack)-1)
{
    echo $dir_stack[$i].'<br>';
    if ($dir = opendir($dir_stack[$i]))
    {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
        {
            if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && false == is_dir($dir_stack[$i].$file))
            {
                unlink($dir_stack[$i].$file);
            }
            elseif ($file != "." && $file != "..")
            {
                array_push($dir_stack,$dir_stack[$i].$file.'/');
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }
    $i++;
}
$i = count($dir_stack)-1;
while ($i >= 0)
{
    rmdir($dir_stack[$i]);
    $i--;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the code i have found and surprisingly it worked

```
<?php

$dir_stack = array('filedirectory'); // put the directory to delete here **NOTE** everything in this will be deleted.
$i = 0;
while ($i <= count($dir_stack)-1)
{
    echo $dir_stack[$i].'<br>';
    if ($dir = opendir($dir_stack[$i]))
    {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
        {
            if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && false == is_dir($dir_stack[$i].$file))
            {
                unlink($dir_stack[$i].$file);
            }
            elseif ($file != "." && $file != "..")
            {
                array_push($dir_stack,$dir_stack[$i].$file.'/');
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }
    $i++;
}
$i = count($dir_stack)-1;
while ($i >= 0)
{
    rmdir($dir_stack[$i]);
    $i--;
}

?>
```

Comment: Great! Looks like the code I found and in the comment I put in. A happy ending after all.

Comment: I can put in an answer if you wish, sure.

Comment: i am not forcing you ;)

Comment: LOL, I know. It's best to close the question properly. I will `+1` yours.

Comment: Am just glad that your problem was resolved. :) Cheers